# How to convert date column from INT to DATE type in large CSV files?

Tags: dolphindb, data-transform, load-csv

I have a CSV file of over 30 GB, and I want to load and store it into a DolphinDB database using the `loadTextEx` function. The file contains a column named “date” which is stored as INT type, with values like “20230731”. I would like to convert the column into the DATE type (i.e., 2023.07.31). How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to use the `transform` (unary function) parameter of [`loadTextEx`](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/l/loadTextEx.html), or asking how to create a modified CSV file prior to ingestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a UDF where the function [temporalParse](https://www.dolphindb.com/help200/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/t/temporalParse.html#temporalparse) can be applied to convert data types, and then pass this UDF to the *transform* parameter in `loadTextEx`. Here is an example:

```
// establish a database connection
db = database("dfs://snapshot_L2_TSDB")  
// specify the format for converted date and time to match the database which is partitioned by date and hash
def transType(mutable memTable)
{
   return memTable.replaceColumn!(`DataTimeStamp,temporalParse( "20221001"+string(memTable.DataTimeStamp),"yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss.SSS"))
}
// import the data
tmpTB=loadTextEx(dbHandle=db, tableName=`snapshot_L2_TSDB_t, partitionColumns=`DataTimeStamp`SecurityID, filename=dataFilePath,schema=schemaTB ,sortColumns=`SecurityID`DataTimeStamp,transform=transType);
```